# How to add to objects that take int arrays as arguments

Tags: java, arrays, object

For an assignment in one of my classes, I have to add two Poly objects that are made up of int arrays. I have a method called add that is supposed to take in a Poly as an argument and add it to the current Poly object (Poly1.add(Poly2)), a Poly represents a polynomial so it should add the coefficients of each array. How can I get each array out of its Poly so that I can add them?

```
public class Poly
{
    private int[] coefficients2;

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

    Poly(int[] coefficients){
        coefficient2 = coefficients;
    }

    public Poly add(Poly a)
    {
        Poly b = new Poly(coefficientList);
        Poly c = null;
        if (coefficientList.length-1 >= a.degree())
        {
            c = new Poly(new int[coefficientList.length-1]); 
        }
        else if (coefficientList.length-1 < a.degree())
        {
            c = new Poly(new int[a.degree()]);
        }
        //This is where I don't know what to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need some kind of loop, inside which you might do operations like `c.coefficients2[i] = coefficients2[i] + a.coefficients2[i];`  (Not going to post a complete answer, since this is homework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object is operating on another instance of the same class, it has direct access to anything in the other instance... or you can define getter methods which access the values or data structures you need.

Comment: ... and also direct access to anything in the other instance that _is_ declared private.  Access modifiers work at the class level, not the object level.

Comment: Right. Sorry; momentary neuron short-circuit; thanks for catching it.